# converts numeric values into electric signals?

Tags: signals

Suppose, you enter 15 in computer. This is a numeric value. How a computer can convert this numeric value into electric signals like:
1 -> True-> Pass electricity
0 -> False -> don't pass electricity

Experts  will say that numeric value will be converted in to binary. But think one thing, Computer is an electric machine and there is a flow of electron, nothing else. How this type of machine can convert any number into electronic signal?

If you cannot clearly understand my question then ask me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an electronics/physics question, NOT a programming question.

Comment: Interesting question, but wrong site. A solid answer to this question takes a book.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I don't think you need a book or a physicist to tell someone that software is nothing but the representation of a hardware state. You don't have to get something from software to hardware because it is already there. Every programmer should know that so his question is perfectly suitable for a programming community.
If you have a basic question on sausages you ask your local butcher or maybe a chef. You usually don't consult a biologist just because sausages contain organic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of literature and ressources on how a computer works. Try wikipedia, youtube, google to find something that suits your level of understanding.

For your question the ALU might be of special interest:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit

Also read something about memory, control unit and transistors.

A computer is nothing but a combination of memory, processors and data busses.
Its is a super miniaturized electronic circuit.

A modern CPU alone comprises about 3-5 billion!!! transistors.

You can store a logic states (bits)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)
Compare them
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate
Do arrithmetic operations on them... You name it.

All happens in hardware. Software is just a representation of that hardware states. Software is nothing but a huge amount of bits arranged in a clever way so these bits will do something useful.
In case of a computer you arrange all those bits in a way that something is displayed on your screen.

You think you're doing it in software but actually everything is hardware. So entering a number on your computer is nothing but pushing an electric switch that triggers a chain reaction in your computers electronics which finally ends up as a polarization state on som of your LCDs pixels. You never had to get something from software to hardware. It was always there.

Comment: Thanks a lot to give to a pathway to gain the knowledge.